# How to find largest and smallest number in c

Tags: c

I have found the solution in particular size of array. 
However, how can I get the largest and smallest numbers without asking to input the size of the array? thanks

e.g. It will only return 65 and -1 when I input numbers like 1, 0, -1, 5, 43, 65. I want to ignore the step for entering the size of the array which is 6 for this case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a[50],size,i,big,small;

  printf("\nEnter the size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d",&size);
  printf("\nEnter %d elements in to the array: ", size);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

  big=a[0];
  for(i=1;i<size;i++){
    if(big<a[i])
      big=a[i];
  }
  printf("Largest element: %d",big);

  small=a[0];
  for(i=1;i<size;i++){
    if(small>a[i])
      small=a[i];
  }
  printf("Smallest element: %d",small);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: but in ur code ` scanf("%d",&size);` you r asking the size?

Comment: Assuming the max array size is 50, you could just count how many times the user types in a number, and then that counter would be the size. You'd have to have a way for the user to stop inputting values though (like typing 'x' for example). If you don't know ahead of time the max size of the array, you'll have to use malloc(), which I don't recommend.

Comment: Where are you hoping to get the values from?

Comment: may as well combined all three loops while you're at it. And if all you want is the largest and smallest, I see little sense in the array *at all*.

Comment: Why do you believe you need an array for this?

Answer (score 3):

I'll go you one further. You don't need an array for this in the first place, thereby making the size-input-avoidance trivial (there is no need for it, because there is no array):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int val;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (scanf("%d", &val) == 1)
    {
        int big = val, small = val;
        do
        {
            if (big < val)
                big = val;
            if (val < small)
                small = val;

            printf("Enter number: ");
            fflush(stdout);

        } while (scanf("%d", &val) == 1);

        printf("Largest element: %d\n",big);
        printf("Smallest element: %d\n",small);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need though for `limits.h` and the initializing to its extremes, is there?

Comment: @Jongware true about not initializing to its extremes, but redundant  sets of input and prompts.  Clean enough for OP and with input error checking. +1.

Comment: @chux I was hitting the traditional `big=INT_MIN, small=INT_MAX` and single input sets, but never liked the edge case reports on no-input (i.e. EOF on inception) in case you're wondering why they're not there. As is, no input means no output.

Comment: @WhozCraig Agree strongly that with no input should have an output the does not say `big=INT_MIN, small=INT_MAX`.  Just like to avoid redundant code like `printf("Enter number: "); if (scanf("%d", &val) == 1)` --- more maintenance.  Of course in this small snippet - no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

could define a macro which lets you calculate the number of entries in an array

```
#define ArrayLength(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
...
int x;
for(x=0;x<ArraLength(myArray);x++){...}
```